# boost::regex, match_results::operator[] - Mysterious "sub += 2" line

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I have an issue accessing sub-matches from boost::match_results class.
When I examine the program in debugger, match_results::m_subs array contains exactly what I expect:

- [0] Is the full match.
- [1] And further are submatches. They match exactly as expected.

However, when I try to acces the submatches using operator[] and index of the submatch starting with 1, I don't get what I want. The reason is hidden in boost source:

```
const_reference operator[](int sub) const
   {
      if(m_is_singular && m_subs.empty())
         raise_logic_error();
      sub += 2;                                             //< WTF?
      if(sub < (int)m_subs.size() && (sub >= 0))
      {
         return m_subs[sub];
      }
      return m_null;
   }
```

I'm totally confused about this. The documentation says I just access n-th submatch using [n], but in code, there's this weird offset everywhere.

Please tell me I'm not insane :)

Checked boost versions: 1.54 and 1.53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two elements in the `m_subs` vector property of the `boost::match_results` class defined in `match_results.hpp` are reserved for storing the prefix and suffix. Their exact meanings are:

```
m_subs[0]           - suffix
m_subs[0].first     - the end position of the match
m_subs[0].second    - the end position of the input text
m_subs[0].matched   - m_subs[0].first != m_subs[0].second
m_subs[1]           - prefix
m_subs[1].first     - the start position of the input text
m_subs[1].second    - the start position of the match
m_subs[1].matched   - m_subs[1].first != m_subs[1].second
```

The match positions of capture group $0 are stored in m_subs[2], $1 in m_subs[3], etc, which can be referenced through the match_results class via [0], [1], etc. That is why you can see the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) 2 added in several places.

Have a look at how match_results' `suffix` and `prefix` methods are implemented:

```
   const_reference prefix() const
   {
      if(m_is_singular)
         raise_logic_error();
      return (*this)[-1];
   }

   const_reference suffix() const
   {
      if(m_is_singular)
         raise_logic_error();
      return (*this)[-2];
   }
```

Since this has been so for quite a while I would not be quick to assume this is causing your particular problem. If you need more help please ask another question containing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) outlining your problem.

P.S. you're not insane (the above is just really terrible code)

Comment: Phew! My sanity is saved!
I know "thank you" comments should be avoided, but seriously, thanks!